# no such service: laravel.test

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I'm a Dockers / Sail beginner and wanted to give it a try with a new Laravel project.

So, when I execute a Laravel fresh install, and i run `sail up` i get this error:

```
no such service: laravel.test
```

However, `http://localhost` returns the expected result.

But `http://laravel.test` doesn't return anything.

Just updated PHP, Laravel and Dockers - so they are running on the latest versions.

Do you know how can I fix this?

EDIT: Added the whole docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s   
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        links:
            - mysql:mysql
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        environment:
            MYSQL_USERNAME: "${DB_USERNAME}"
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
            PMA_HOST: mysql    
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
```

Comment: The reason laravel.test as a domain does not work, is because sail does not create a domain for you. If you want this to work, you need to add it to your hosts file. About the sail up: it should exist in your docker-compose file, did you chanhe the name of your service?

Comment: Thanks @onlineThomas - i will look into host files and come back with an update.

And yes, in `docker-compose.yml` i have `laravel.tests` as a service (I edited the question so that it contains the whole docker-compose.yml file).

Answer (score 2):

## the name

The name `laravel.test` for this service is poorly chosen. All the other services give a more proper clue as to what service is running in the container.
In the case of `laravel.test`, there runs a [php built-in web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), which is [kept running by a supervisor](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/runtimes/8.1/supervisord.conf#L8). A better name would be `php_webserver` for example.

## not being able to access laravel.test

Domains are bought (although it's more like renting) from a domain registrar. However the tld `.test` is [reserved for testing and can't be bought](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.test). The most common way to create a fake domain for testing is by modifying your `hosts` file.

- Windows: `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`
- Mac: `/etc/hosts`
- Linux: `/etc/hosts`

This file requires admin access, so you need to start your text editor as admin to make changes. Here you can make a newline entry with the content

```
127.0.0.1 laravel.test
```

This will make your OS check for localhost when trying to access `laravel.test`.

You can of course keep using 127.0.0.1 to check your site like always.

Answer (score 1):

You should first add it to your project:

```
composer require laravel/sail --dev
```

after that, instal sail:

```
php artisan sail:install
```

then:

```
./vendor/bin/sail up // or sail up
```

Comment: Sail is installed, because all docker containers are running on `sail up` - but only `http://localhost` delivers the website content.

Also, documentation clearly states: Laravel Sail is automatically installed with all new Laravel applications so you may start using it immediately https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#installation

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue by adding

```
172.19.0.1      laravel.test
```

in host file on my pc. i am using liunx mint

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because of laravel.test domain not registered in your system
so if you use Linux use [@Saravana Sai's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15177375/saravana-sai) answer

but if you use windows the host file exists in

```
C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
```

note: you need administrative privileges to edit this file